# Cutting a circle from the hyperbolic plane

Tags: moduli-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let **D** be the Poincare' disk  its natural hyperbolic metric and with at least 1 marked point on $\partial D$. Suppose I cut an hyperbolic circle of radius $r$ away from it, then I get a Riemann surface with a boundary $\partial C$, which is *not* a geodesic boundary. However, it is possible to find a Riemannian metric on $D\setminus C$ so that $\partial C$ is now geodetic.

My question is, it is possible to do so without changing the metric on $D\setminus C$, or at least only by a total rescaling?

My intuition is that, if I rescale the whole metric, I can make the geodesic curvature of $\partial C$ small at will, so it should be possible.

I made a tentative proof which is as follows: Quite obviosuly, we need to add an annulus. Any annulus can be written as $A_M = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} |\ R < |z| < 1\}$, $M$ being its modulus given by $$M = \ln{1/R}.$$
It is well known that we can find a generator $\pi_1(A_M)$ which is a geodetic - with respect to the hyperbolic metric of the annulus - of length equal to $\pi/M$ (or something very similar, not really relevant). 
We can of course scale $A_M$ by a multiplication $z \to z/r$, without changing its modulus, this might change the geodetic representative of $\pi_1(A_M)$ to a new one which we call $\gamma$.

Now I glue the outer boundary of the annulus to $\partial C$. This can be done in many ways, because of the twists, but I can use the marked points on $\partial D$ to define this gluing uniquely: we can define marked points on $\partial C$ by projecting them through the old center of $C$.

Now, I argue that the surface I get carries an hyperbolic metric for which the punctures on $\partial D$ are half-cusps and $\gamma$ is a geodetic of length uniquely identified by the (former) radius of $C$, **r**. Indeed, the surface I got is locally isometric to $D$ or to $A_M$ by construction, and this should end the proof.

Am I correct?

EDIT:

I forgot the uniqueness part which is at follows: Suppose two annuli exists with different moduli and the property of having exterior radius **r**, then we can glue them together by this common circle and we get a surface with two geodetic boundaries of different lengths, which is impossible.

RE-EDIT:
I made a lot of confusion in asking the question, so I restate it completely:

Basically: Is the moduli space of the Poincare' disk with $n$ marked points on the boundary, and a marked circle inside, equivalent to the moduli space of Riemann surfaces with two geodesic boundaries, and $n$ marked points on one of them?

I thought I could cut away the circle and then uniquely determine, in terms of its radius, center and relative locations to the markings, an annulus to attach to it so that I get a Riemann surface with two geodetic boundaries.

Also,I see now that my proof is wrong because I attach an infinite length component of the annulus to the former circle, and that does not make any sense.

Comment: "is it possible to find a metric on D minus C"... "without changing the metric on D minus C" ??

Comment: Sorry I made an huge confusion, now it should be at least a well posed question.

Comment: Even with your re-edit, the question remains very unclear. For starters, what do you mean "the moduli space of Riemann surfaces with two geodesic boundaries": Riemann surfaces are object of complex analysis. You probably mean "Riemannian surfaces". Next, what is your notion of the moduli space in the context of Riemannian metrics: Are we talking about Riemannian metrics (with some boundary conditions) up to conformal equivalence? Thirdly, what do you mean by "equivalent" regarding these moduli spaces? Do you mean diffeomorphic as orbifolds? I suggest you ask a new question and delete this one.

Comment: 1)I meant hyperbolic Riemann surfaces, not Riemannian. 
3)Is a Poincare' disk with $n$ marked punctures and 1 marked circle conformally equivalent to an Hyperbolic Riemann surfaces with two geodesic (with respect to the natural hyperbolic metric) boundaries and $n$ marked punctures on one of the two components? Is it possible to use punctures locations, circle location and radius as coordinates on the moduli space of these latter kind of surfaces?
(For better definitions, https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.1676)